# SQL Grouping using left join

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables with related data. One table is for `products` and the other `price`. In the price table one product may appear several times. How can I return the result by grouping.

Below is my Query but the output is not with Group

```
   SELECT distinct 
          p.Product, 
          p.Qty, 
          MAX(pr.netprice) 

   FROM Products p 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Price pr ON p.Product=pr.Product 
   WHERE p.brand='' 
   GROUP BY p.Product, p.Qty
```

Comment: This should work. How do you want the result to look?

Comment: What is the intension using distinct here ?

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the products and their HIGHEST price (max) in the price table?  I can write the query but don't think I fully understand what you want.

Comment: Could you give some sample dat and sample results you want?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably leave the `Qty` out of the `group by`, like this:

```
 SELECT p.Product, 
        MAX(pr.netprice) 

   FROM Products p 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Price pr ON p.Product=pr.Product 
   WHERE p.brand='' 
   GROUP BY p.Product
```

Comment: This won't run, you have to remove p.Qty from the select list also.

Comment: @Jan - true.  This can't possibly run as you'll either need to have the column in a function or put it in the GROUP BY

Comment: Dipspaly this  error if group remove for Qty ----is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. That's what I meant. Come to think of it, depending on what you want to do it might be appropriate to leave out the Qty, or use SUM(Qty) or MAX(Qty).

Comment: if use SUM(Qty) it return more rows as  In the price table one product may appear several times & using Max(Qty) return rows with max value.. ( using sum & max) doesnt help.. Any other way to modify the query to get correct output

Comment: Well, what would be the correct output? I'm just guessing what you want the query to tell you :)

Comment: (also, I agree that `distinct` is unneccessary here... removing it.)

Comment: tried both ways using distinct & without but still the output is same.. Can any one assist?

Comment: But! But. What output do you want to get? Can you give an example input and output?